# several conditions in apache mod rewrite to make custom URLs

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

In my domain example.com , I want to put all page files in a directory at root for example named **file**. So for example I put *about.php* the *file* directory and want to let users to access this page with this URL : **example.com/about**
or for example put *user* directory in the *file* directory and put *login.php* in it , and want to let users to access it with : **example.com/user/login**
In fact I want to remove .php and the *file* from the URLs.

**AND**

If those files don't exist , it should load a default file like *index.php* at root. for example the URL example.com/blabla should be mapped to the *index.php*

In fact , I want to make two conditions in mod rewrite with the mentioned **priority**.

**notice :** of course I should be able to use variables like $_GET at files like *about.php*

**UPDATE :** in summary , it should work with this logic :

```
if the URI isn't a file or directory{
    if file/URI.php is a file
        load file/URI.php
    else
        load index.php
}
```

some body gave an answer to use `ErrorDocument 404 index.php` , but it's a really bad idea (and now has deleted his answer !)

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conditional rewrite (if the pages exist) sounds like a bad and complicated idea, if it even is possible.

I would rewrite everything to `/index.php` and control everything from there:

- If the components of the url lead to an existing page, use / include that content;
- If no valid page is found, present your original index content.

Example redirect rules for your situation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Will include the requested path in `id` and append the variables from the original query string (the `QSA` flag).

More specific for your `/user/login` example would be:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ /index.php?path=$1&file=$2 [QSA,L]
```

- [\w-+] : any word character (including `_`) and the `-`

Comment: well I was using exactly this approach, but there are some problems with this way. for example , as mentioned in the question, then the $_GET variable will not represent the query strings and manual parsing should be used , which I don't prefer to do

Comment: @ali Why would `$_GET` not work? You can rewrite everything to `index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&etc.`.

Comment: $_GET works on index.php , but not working on file/pages/about.php which is included by PHP language at index.php file.

Comment: @ali `$_GET` will be available in any file you include. Just don't do any redirects.

Comment: Great! just don't do any redirects!
now I'm using this :
`RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !-d
    
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php`

and $_GET works. but when go to exmaple.com/"fdfd it says forbidden which I don't want. So I was using this trick to avoid this:

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !-d
    
RewriteRule ^[^"] /index.php?id=$1`

which was making $_GET unavailable. would you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: will make me completely happy if solve this little problem too!

Comment: @ali Sorry, I was unclear, don't do any redirects in the php. I'll add  an example rule.